# awk command in gnuplot under windows

Tags: awk, gnuplot, gawk

I use a awk command in a gnuplot script. When I run the script I get the following error message:

```
warning: system() requires support for pipes
```

I also installed gawk from this website [gnuwin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm). Does anybody know why I get this error and what to do to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For gnuplot version 4.6 or earlier you must run the `wgnuplot_pipes.exe` in order to use pipes. Since version 5.0, the `wgnuplot.exe` itself supports pipes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have gnuplot 4.6 and also tried to run the script with `wgnuplot_pipes.exe`. Here I get the error that `the "awk" command is either misspelled or was not found`.

Comment: Well, the `awk.exe` command must be findable by the system. If you open a console and enter `awk` you'll probably get the same message. Edit your `PATH` environment variable to contain the directory where the executable is located.

Comment: I did this and it still doesn't work. Same error as before with `wgnuplot_pipes.exe`. But I found a way to avoid the awk command and use macros instead.